# How to fix the crash happening during conditional copying

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I am trying to store only the alpha characters of a string 's' into my deque of characters using std::copy_if but is giving a crash during the copy statement.

```
std::string s{"Love"};
std::deque<char> dr;
std::deque<char>::reverse_iterator itr =std::copy_if(s.cbegin(),s.cend   (),dr.rbegin(),[](char c){return isalpha(c);});
```

program.exe stopped working

Comment: Does `dr` have enough room for that many characters?

Answer (score 2):

The likely problem is that your `deque` isn't big enough to hold the characters you are copying. `std::copy_if` does not resize the `deque` (how could it since it only has an iterator to work with)? The usual answer is to use a special kind of iterator called a `std::front_insert_iterator` which will call `push_front` to grow the `deque` when elements are copied. You can create a `std::front_insert_iterator` with the function `std::front_inserter`. Like this

```
auto itr = 
    std::copy_if(s.cbegin(), s.cend(),
        std::front_inserter(dr), 
        [](char c){return isalpha(c);});
```

PS there is also a corresponding `std::back_insert_iterator` and function `std::back_inserter` which are more commonly used. But `std::front_inserter` is appropriate for your case since it seems you want to reverse the sequence of characters when you insert them into the `deque`.

Comment: @JeJo Sorry, you're going to get a regular iterator back from my code, not a reverse iterator. I've fixed that. If it's a problem you can construct a reverse_iterator from the returned iterator.

Comment: @JeJo Sorry another correction. This is what happens when I don't test compile posted code. The iterator returned from `std::copy_if` will be the same type as the iterator passed to the third argument. So in the case above it would be a `std::front_insert_iterator<std::deque<char>>`. It's quite unusual to need the iterator returned from `std::copy_if`, but if you do then it's simplest to declare it as `auto` and let the compiler figure out the type.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. IMHO, your is the clever answer what OP needs. Hence deleting mine. It might be good if you could add the above comment to your answer. ;)

Comment: @john is there any way we specify size of the deque without initialising it. I haven't really seen any case like that.                                                                      PS: I am pretty new to programming btw

Comment: @AyushJindal Yes, just specify the size when you create the deque. For instance `std::deque<char> dr(10);` creates a deque of size 10. JeJo said the same thing in his now deleted answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the key insight _"(how could it since it only has an iterator to work with)"_ that I've routinely missed while being pissed at the crudeness of these std. functions!...